# URL with same parameter , but with different Naming route

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

i have two URL'S one is

```
Route::get(
        '/{cat}/{slug}',
        [
            'uses' => 'User\UserEndController@category',
            'as'=>'showCategory',
            'middleware'=>'web'
        ]
    );
```

and other one is  this

```
Route::get(
        '/{mostParentCat}/{performerSlug}',
        [
            'uses' => 'User\UserEndController@performerWithoutParent',
            'as'=>'performerWithoutParent',
            'middleware'=>'web'
        ]
    );
```

both of them get two parameters after slash
i have to redirect them to different functions.
i know that's not a good way to use same routes but that's a client requirement

Answer (score 0):

If this is a client requirement and you can't do nothing else, I would **create a single route**

`'/{cat}/{slug}'`

and link it to an action which responsibility is to **check what kind of behaviour you need**.

Once you understand what do you need, **you could use two different classes** (one for the `'/{cat}/{slug}'` combination, and one for the `/{mostParentCat}/{performerSlug}`).

Take a look, also, to the **strategy design pattern**. It could help you.

Hope it helps :)